# .pngs not showing in browser

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
</title>
</head>
<html>
<body>



<img id="trafficlight" src=asset[i]>
<button type="button" onclick= changeLights() > change</button>


<script>

var asset=["X:\HTML CA\Assets\red.png",
    "X:\HTML CA\Assets\red+orange.png",
    "X:\HTML CA\Assets\green.png",
    "X:\HTML CA\Assets\orange.png"];
var i=0;
function changeLights(){
    i=i+1;
    if (i===3){
        i =0;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('trafficlight').src=asset[i]
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The .pngs just show as little black squares with x's in them. Any help would be appreciated. I can't upload the images to a website as we have restrictions on web use so need to keep my assets on the PC I'm using

Comment: try adding file:// in front of each path, and change \ by /

Comment: If you paste the png URLs in your browser, do you see the images? If no, it's problem of the paths and not of the code, if yes, maybe you should encode your URL to avoid spaces and symbols

Comment: This is client side.. client side has no access to the absolute disk storage, you need to use a relative route.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question; the whole point of SO is for others to be helped by the question and answers too.

Answer (score 0):

the images would need to be in the root of your website, or in a folder in your website, examples:
if your local website path is: `C:\users\name\desktop\websites\website`
the images should be in: `C:\users\name\desktop\websites\website` aswell, or in `C:\users\name\desktop\websites\website\path\to\folder\here`

actual html:

```
<img src="path/to/img.png">
```

or upload them to an external image server, though this could mean a broken site later on as the image link might be changed/deleted or the image itself could be deleted (ei: [http://imgur.com/imgid.png](https://imgur.com/imgid.png))

actual html:

```
<img src="http://imgur.com/imgid.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser expects to find the image in the same folder as the web page.

If you store images in a sub-folder then you need to include the folder name in the src attribute like on the example:

```
<img src="/images/html5.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line does not work:

```
<img id="trafficlight" src=asset[i]>
```

The `src` attribute is not parsed as Javascript. You could manually set the `src` attribute to the first element or do it through Javascript underneath the markup.

Your function should also be changed too:

```
function changeLights(){
    i=i+1;
    if (i===3){
        i =0;
    }
    document.getElementById('trafficlight').src=asset[i]
}
```

Since it, otherwise, would completely skip setting the image when resetting to 0.

The `onclick` attribute on the `<button>` should be a string like this: `"changeLights()"`.

You should have the page title inside the `<title>`-tags not meta-data.

Your paths needs to escape <kbd>\</kbd> or change them to <kbd>/</kbd> And due to security policies, your browser is not allowed to load local ressource, so you will have to use a relative path.